# Apache ReWrite Rule excluding URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am simply trying to exclude a `REQUEST_URI` match from my RewriteRule.

I would like to redirect all URIs, except coming from `/api/` This sounds simple, and all the references I have looked at, show that I am doing it correctly, yet it still doesn't work (ie, not redirecting).

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/redirect [R=302,L]
```

This certainly seems simple, but not working (ie, not redirecting). If I remove the exclamation point, and test to only redirect if it matches the pattern, then it works (ie, when I remove the exclamation point, a redirect takes place when I enter `http://www.example.com/api/`). But, it doesn't work (ie, a redirect doesn't take place when I include the exclamation point) for excluding.

I've looked at the Rewrite log, and that hasn't helped etiher.

Comment: What does "work" or "not work" mean? What's the request you're trying with? Maybe there are other rules?